# Devise error: UnknownFormat at /users/sign_up.user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

I've looked through similar questions but none of those answers seem to fit my problem.

When I visit the `new_user_registration_path` `localhost:3000/users/sign_up.user`, I get the following error: `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

`Devise/registrations/new.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: new_user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
 <%= devise_error_messages! %>

 <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
   <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

 <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

 <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

 <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %><br /></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
    resources :users
```

In my `ApplicationController` I've included (based on responses to similar questions):

```
respond_to :html, :json, :xml
```

This is my first time really using devise and I'm at a loss. I don't know if making my own `RegistrationController` would help, as I can't determine the problem. Any ideas? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me the correct URL is

localhost:3000/users/sign_up

without the .user at the end.

You should see the railscasts on Devise, if you are signed up for Railscasts, its worth it.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-devise-revised